RandomizedSearchCV with NeuralNetClassifier gives different tuning parameters each run
I am trying to get the best parameters for the DNN Model using RandomizedSearchCV, but each time I run the code I get different sets of best parameters.
I tried to add random_state=42 to GridSearchCV, but it seems not acceptable.
Step of my experiment:

I set the random seed for my experiment:
seed = 42
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
# Enforce deterministic behavior in PyTorch
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False


I have divided the dataset into training and test datasets:


data_indices = list(range(2400)) 
train_indices, test_indices = train_test_split(
    data_indices, random_state=42, test_size=0.20, shuffle=True, stratify=y)  

X_train, y_train = X[train_indices], Y[train_indices]
X_test, y_test =  X[test_indices], Y[test_indices]   


I am using NeuralNetClassifier from the Skorch package to tune the hyperparameter with RandomizedSearchCV:

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from skorch import NeuralNetClassifier 
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV 
 
# Define the model
class MlpNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, layer_sizes=[], activation=nn.ReLU):
        super(MlpNet, self).__init__()
        layers = []
        self.act = activation
        for l_id in range(len(layer_sizes) - 1):
            layers.append(nn.Linear(layer_sizes[l_id], layer_sizes[l_id + 1]))
            if l_id < len(layer_sizes) - 2:  # No activation or batchnorm for the last layer
                layers.append(nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=layer_sizes[l_id + 1], affine=False))
                layers.append(self.act())
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(*layers)
        self.prob = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.float()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layers(x) 
        return self.prob(x) 

# Create the model
model = NeuralNetClassifier(
    module=MlpNet,
    criterion=nn.BCELoss, 
    optimizer=optim.Adam, 
    device=device,   
    verbose=False
) 

param_grid = {
    'optimizer__lr': [0.001, 0.01], 
    'module__layer_sizes': [    [ 108,  256, 256, 128, 1],
                                [ 108,  256, 256, 1],
                                [ 108,  128, 64, 1],
                                [ 108,  128, 128, 1], 
                            ],
    'module__activation': [nn.ReLU,  nn.Tanh, nn.Sigmoid], 
    'batch_size': [10, 30, 50, 80, 100],
    'max_epochs': [10, 50, 80, 100]  
}  
   
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=model, param_distributions=param_grid, n_iter=5, 
                                   scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=4, cv=skf.split(X_train,y_train), random_state=42 )

grid_result = random_search.fit(X_train.float(), torch.unsqueeze(y_train.float(), 1))
 

print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_)) 

I have seen this question from StackOverflow, but none have solved my queries.

Why i am getting different tuning parameters each run when using GridSearchCV with random forest regressor?
Reproducing Model results from RandomizedSearchCV
RandomizedSearchCV independently on models in an ensemble
hyperparameter tuning in sklearn using RandomizedSearchCV taking lot of time
Conditional tuning of hyperparameters with RandomizedSearchCV in scikit-learn

Each time I run the code, I get different sets of best parameters. These different best hyperparameters give different training and test accuracy.
I want to reproduce the result of hyperparameter tuning. How can I get the same set of hyperparameters in every run?

"I tried to add random_state=42 to GridSearchCV, but it seems not acceptable." Why do you consider this not acceptable? If you don't want randomness, fixing the random state seems to be exactly what you want as well.
